# PHP - Where should I call ini_set?

Tags: php

I am looking for a best practice for where I should place the statement
ini_set.

For example,

```
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I normally place them all in my `index.php` file as early as is practical. Normally, immediately after defining constants for the root directory of my application and before anything could go wrong (for example before any `require`s)

Comment: For this specific setting, how do you inform the user that the website requires cookies?

Thank you

Comment: @qo987 when your application requires a cookie that isn't there